# Laravel 5: sorting child records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

It does not sort child records. I have a field in db called `order`
Here is my code:

```
$offer = Offer::find($id);
$offer->service->sortBy('order', true);

return $offer;
```

Although I get an array of services if I use sortBy, without it there is just JSON data.

Any ideas why it does not sort? Thank you in advance.
If you need extra code, please let me know.

Comment: The second parameter of `sortBy` is not a `true/false`, it's `int $options = SORT_REGULAR`.

Comment: You can add this as right answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `sortBy` is not a `true`/`false`, it's `int $options = SORT_REGULAR`. Laravel likely doesn't know what to make of your `true` value.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:** I assume that **$offer->service** is a **OneToMany/ManyToMany** relationship - the name suggests it's not, but if you expect an array of services then it must be **OneToMany/ManyToMany** relationship.

In order to get the services sorted by order you need to load offers this way:

```
$offer = Offer::with(['service' => function($builder) {
  $builder->sortBy('order');
}])->get();
```